# Is there any way that we can use two custom error messages using spring-boot custom validation?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using the below custom validation code to validate personName and it seems to be working fine, but the problem is when am passing an EMPTY string, it is giving same error message instead of the empty error message. Can someone please help me with this?

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {PersonNameValidator.class})
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface PersonName {

    /**
     * Default error message defined for the validator.
     *
     * @return message
     */
    String message() default "invalid person name";

    /**
     * Method to define groups parameters for validation.
     *
     * @return groups
     */
    Class[] groups() default {};

    /**
     * Method to load payload.
     *
     * @return payload
     */
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}


public class PersonNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PersonName, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String name, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (name.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("must not be Empty");
        } else if (!name.matches("(?=^(?!\\s*$).+)(^[^±!@£$%^&*_+§€#¢§¶•«\\\\/<>?:;|=]{1,256}$)")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name should start with uppercase.");
        }
        return true;
    }
}


@Data
public class NameDto {

    @NotNull
    @PersonName
    private String family1Name;

    @PersonName
    private String family2Name;

    @NotNull
    @PersonName
    private String givenName;

    @PersonName
    private String middleName;
}
```

Getting NullPointerException

Comment: nullpointer due _if (name.length() == 0)_ use _if (null == name || 0 == name.length())_ as in my example

Comment: @DirkDeyne It worked. Thank you

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @Name
  @NotEmpty(message = "name cannot be empty")
  String name;
```

should work

but if you want to join constraint you should use a custom `ConstraintValidator` add provide this validator via `@Constraint(validatedBy = {YourCustomValidator.class}`
 see example below

---

*full example*

used dependency *spring-boot-starter-validation* (not needed if you use *spring-boot-starter-web*)

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
upper.name=dirk
```

application

```
package stackoverflow.demo;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SoCustomValidationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SoCustomValidationApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
class ConfigurationLoader{
  final MyCustomValidatedProperties config;

  ConfigurationLoader(MyCustomValidatedProperties config){
    this.config = config;
  }

  @EventListener()
  void showName() {
    System.err.println("name is: " + config.getName());
  }
}

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "upper")
class MyCustomValidatedProperties {

  @Uppercase
  @NotEmpty(message = "name cannot be empty")
  String name;

  public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

  public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Constraint(validatedBy = {ValidNameValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@interface Uppercase {
  String message() default "name should start with uppercase";

  Class[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

class ValidNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Uppercase, String> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String name, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (null == name || 0 == name.length() ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("name cannot be empty.");
    } else if(!name.matches("^([A-Z][a-z]+)")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("name should start with uppercase.");
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

```
Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'upper' to stackoverflow.demo.MyCustomValidatedProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0094cdb failed:

    Property: upper.name
    Value: dirk
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:1:12
    Reason: name should start with uppercase
```

and if you leave upper.name empty

```
upper.name=
```

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

```
Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'upper' to stackoverflow.demo.MyCustomValidatedProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29925f50 failed:

    Property: upper.name
    Value: 
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:1:12
    Reason: name cannot be empty

    Property: upper.name
    Value: 
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:1:12
    Reason: name should start with uppercase
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need one error message like for example if we pass empty string it should give 'must not be empty' and if the name is invalid then the default one

Comment: @srielathaU is a ConstraintValidator useful?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have tried the way you suggested but getting NullPointerException. I will post my complete code here. Please take a look. Thanks